# Hisat2 with job array

Tags: shell, alignment, slurm, rna-seq

I want to use Hsat2 instead of bowtie2 but
I have a problem with my script:

```
    !/bin/bash
    ##SBATCH --time=5:00:00
    #SBATCH --nodes=1
    #SBATCH --ntasks=1
    #SBATCH --mem=32G
    #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16   # Nb of threads we want to run on
    #SBATCH -o log/slurmjob-%j
    #SBATCH --job-name=hist2
    #SBATCH --partition=short
    #SBATCH --array=0-5

    module load gcc/4.8.4 HISAT2/2.0.5 samtools/1.3

SCRATCHDIR=/storage/scratch/"$USER"/"$SLURM_JOB_ID"

    DATABANK="$HOME/projet/GRCm38/bwa"

    OUTPUT="$HOME"/hisat2
    mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"
    mkdir -p "$SCRATCHDIR"
    cd "$SCRATCHDIR"

    #Define an array to optimize tasks

    ARRAY=()

    hisat2 -p 8 -x "$DATABANK"/all.* -1  "$HOME"/chipseq/${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}_R1_trim.fastq.gz -2 "$HOME"/chipseq/${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}_R2_trim.fastq.gz -S Hisat2_out.${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}.sam | samtools view -b -S - | samtools sort - -o Hisat2_out.${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}.mapped.sorted.bam 

    samtools idxstats Hisat2_out.${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}.mapped.sorted.bam > $OUTPUT/"$HOME/hisat2/hisat2_indxstat".log

    mv  "$SCRATCHDIR" "$OUTPUT"
```

The error occurs on this one

> ${ARRAY[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} : variable without link

Thank you for the help !

Comment: you allocate an empty array with `ARRAY=()`, but you never put any variables in that ARRAY. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but even if I do put variables inside it doesn't work